# Распределение ответственности между основной VM и диалоговой

Tags: c#, mvvm

Допустим, у нас есть UsersViewModel - VM для отображения списка пользователей и добавления их.

```
internal class UsersViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddUserCommand { get; }

    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        AddUserCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(AddUserAsync);            
    }

    private async Task AddUserAsync()
    {
        //Что-то делаем
    }
}
```

Для добавления пользователя вызывается AddUserDialogViewModel - диалоговое окно.

```
internal class AddUserDialogViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
{
    //Какие-то свойства пользователя

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CancelCommand { get; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> SaveCommand { get; }

    public AddUserDialogViewModel()
    {
        CancelCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(Cancel);
        SaveCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveAsync);
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        //Отменяем добавление и возвращем DialogResult.Cancel
    }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        //Каким-либо образом добавляем пользователя
    }
}
```

**И вот тут начинается мой вопрос. Как с точки зрения SOLID правильно сделать это добавление?**

За все время я нашел всего 2 способа:

1. Напрямую пробросить класс **IUSerService** в DialogViewModel через конструктор и чтобы уже внутри вызывались нужные методы.

```
internal class AddUserDialogViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> SaveCommand { get; }

    public AddUserDialogViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        SaveCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SaveAsync);
    }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await _userService.AddAsync();
    }
}
```

На первый взгляд выглядит логично, но должно ли диалоговое окно знать вообще каким образом происходит добавление пользователя? На мой взгляд, эта VM должна собрать нужные данные именно для добавления и отдать их кому-то, и на этом заканчивается её зона ответственности.

2. Пробросить в конструктор делегат.

```
internal class UsersViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    private async Task AddUserAsync()
    {
        var handler = async () =>
        {
            await _userService.AddAsync();                
        };
        var vm = new AddUserDialogViewModel(handler);
    }
}

 internal class AddUserDialogViewModel : DialogViewModelBase
 {
     private Func<Task> _handler;

     public AddUserDialogViewModel(Func<Task> handler)
     {
         _handler = handler;
     }

     private async Task SaveAsync()
     {
         await _handler();
     }
 }
```

Этот способ мне нравится больше, т.к я скрываю реализацию.

Comment: Обычно, диалоговые окна делаются при помощи некого сервиса, который принимает условную VM и на ее основе формирует нужный вывод, после этого, диалог возвращает наружу класс, содержащий в себе `enum` нажатой кнопки, и данные. Ну если очень грубо, то что-то типа этого `var dialResult = await DialogService.Show(new TestViewModel ("Хотите принять участие в опросе?", "Да", "Брр, нет"));` далее `if (dialResult.Button == DialogButton.OK) { ...Write($"Ваш ответ {dialResult.Data}"); }` (пример абстрактный, но суть думаю поняли).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я спросил про зону ответственности, а не как вызывать диалоговое окно или же получить от него результат. Вы меня не поняли)

UPD: И в мое случае диалоговое окно(в данном вопросе) - это не простой вопрос, а большой UserControl с кучей свойств и валидацией. Да и то это еще упрощенно)

Comment: Ну почему, ваш вопрос выделен прям жирным `Как с точки зрения SOLID правильно сделать это добавление?`, я и даю на него комментарий, где прямым текстом говорю, что диалоговое окно должно быть вызвано отдельным сервисом, которое должно принимать конкретную VM и отдавать конкретный объект, на основе которого уже вызывающая VM будет делать свои действия. Никаких "знаний" про другие слои у него быть не должно, оно должно быть максимально абстрактно, получая все данные извне, по сути, как любой UI контрол.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а если внутри контрола(диалог) нам нужно подтянуть какие-то данные? Например, меняем дату и от этой даты нужно получить уникальный id через какой-то внешний класс. Заранее мы не можем знать какую дату выберет пользователь и как тут быть?

Comment: Тогда это не диалог, а полноценное окно, со своим контентом и своей логикой) Диалоговое окно - это когда вы у пользователя что-то хотите узнать, быстро и без каких либо лишних элементов. Условно "Ваше имя?", "Уверены, что хотите закрыть?", и т.д. Ну вот например [документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/design/controls/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs). Ну а если у вас там условная запись в кино, где вы при выборе зала подгружаете данные из базы с доступными днями, то это уже полноценное окно/страница, которое как и обычное, имеет встроенные зависимости, с которыми и работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в моем понимании диалоговое окно - то, что открывется поверх текущего. Я могу делать и навигацию(полную замену текущего UserControl), но именно добавление/редактирование/удаление мне нравится открывать поверх текущего, поэтому так вопрос и назвал)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и в таком случае(полноценное окно, которое я открываю поверх текущего в рамках одной window) вы бы в него пробрасывали зависимости или же их скрыли через делегаты?

Comment: Ваше право писать проект так, как угодно вам) Если мы сейчас говорим про "окна", то чем это окно отличается от основного окна? Почему в VM этого окна не может быть своих зависимостей?